# Using Hashids in a for loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, hashids

I'm trying to use the hashids plugin to hash `ticket_id` within a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var hashids = new Hashids("", 5);
    var id = hashids.encode(result[i].ticket_id);
    console.log(hashids);
    [...]

    html += '<tr class="ticketClick" data-url="' + baseURL + id>' [...]
}
```

HTML for a table is dynamically generated based on the `result` passed by an ajax call. When the table row is clicked I redirect to the url in the data-url attribute.

The problem is that hashids doesn't run and therefore `id` isn't being appended to the url.

The console log of `hashids` produces:

```
Hashids {version: "1.0.2", minAlphabetLength: 16, sepDiv: 3.5, guardDiv: 12, errorAlphabetLength: "error: alphabet must contain at least X unique characters"…}
```

I've searched for the error and didn't find anything...

What I find strange is that if I pass an integer directly into the hashids method like:

`var id = hashids.encode(20);`

The encode works and returns the expected hash.

A console.log of `result[i].ticket_id` returns the expected integer, so the for loop is doing it's job properly. Declaring `new Hashids()` outside the `for` loop doesn't seem to make a difference. So I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure it is a number and not a string?

Comment: heh... yes. That was the problem. The ajax call was returning JSON. I just needed to `parseId(result[i].ticket_id)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because of the Ajax function pulling the data in JSON format.

### Solution

Parse the value to an integer:
`parseId(result[i].ticket_id)`